# count with an input from user in Terraform?

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

I want to create a number of resources using terraform depending which number the user enters. The number have to be between 2 and 5.
I tried:
in `vars.tf`:

```
variable "user_count" {
    type = number
    default = 2
    description = "How many number of VMs to create (minimum 2 and no more than 5): "
}
```

The problem here is its creates the resources with the default number 2.

Another case:

```
variable "user_count" {
        type = number
        description = "How many number of VMs to create (minimum 2 and no more than 5): "
    }
```

Here, without the default parameter. I get the message/description, but I/the user can enter anything!
How to make this possible? - the user get a message and verify the number is between 2 and 5, else the resources will not be created.

Any help is appreciate - I am really stuck in it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try [custom validation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#custom-validation-rules)

```
variable "user_count" {
        type = number
        description = "How many number of VMs to create (minimum 2 and no more than 5): "
        validation {
          condition     = var.user_count > 1 && var.user_count < 6
          error_message = "Validation condition of the user_count variable did not meet."
        }
}
```

But maybe better option instead of checking number, will be variable as string and regex to check if value is 2,3,4 or 5.

```
variable "user_count" {
  type        = string
  description = "How many number of VMs to create (minimum 2 and no more than 5): "

  validation {
    # regex(...) fails if it cannot find a match
    condition     = can(regex("2|3|4|5", var.user_count))
    error_message = "Validation condition of the user_count variable did not meet."
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow!!! - I have not thought about `validation` at all. I did not know it existed. Many thanks..I can continue on...know.

Comment: Why would the second option be a better idea? The first option definitely seems better and less surprising to me.

Comment: It all depends if you can type decimal numbers. I just don't recall what number actually is in terraform. If it `int` first one should be better. Can you consider upvoting my reply?

Comment: A Terraform `number` does permit fractional numbers, if that's what you're referring to, but you can use a validation expression like `floor(var.user_count) == var.user_count` to require a whole number. Even if you do take that `regex` approach I'd still recommend using `type = number`; Terraform will automatically convert it to a string just for the second argument to `regex`, while the rest of the module will see `var.user_count` as a number.